# Symfony2 search engine strategy

Tags: symfony, search-engine

I am really stuck at finding a strategy for creating a symfony2 search engine for cars.

The app has a front page with a "quick search" form.

The second page is the search page itself consisting of a fast search form and links from the car attributes(like section carmake, you click on BMW, it is being requeried with the form params together). Trying to use symfony2 mechanisms of form posting and form building I came to the following limitations:

- Form on homepage cannot be sent to some other controller (eg. SearchController), it has to be the same controller the form is rendered on.
- I did not succeed to have the url having params like www.mysite.com/search/2010/2012/.. with form submission
- Redirecting from homepage to search page does not allow sending the search object with it
- After resubmitting the quick form on the search page and using search object, binding form with request succeeds, but the url stays the same (for example www.mysite.com/0/0/0)

Is there an example or a special strategy for symfony2 and creating a search based site?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, SO isn't your personal search engine. You will find [plenty of Bundle](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=search) to handle a search engine and a [great talk](http://xavierbriand.github.com/training-solr/) too.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into Solr, due to it's efficiency, speed and high customization options.